# Calling a methods with parameter

Tags: javascript, html

Here i want to draw a different image animation in 1 function like an orbit track , horizontal move , vertical move in 1 function.

I've read from many source, that i need to call a methods with parameter.

Firstly i try with 1 animation with track like a planet orbit. But my code aren't work at all. What's wrong with my code? 
please help & teach me

```
var circleX = 200;
var circleY = 200; 
var radius = 150;
var length = 0;

var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var speed = 0.1;


function nextxy (circle) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.strokeRect(5, 5, 490, 490);

    //what's wrong with my code below?
    var circle = [
    setX = circleX + Math.cos(length) * radius;
    setY = circleY + Math.sin(length) * radius;
    length += speed;
    ]

context.beginPath();
var img = new Image();
img.src = "rock.png";
context.drawImage(img, setX, setY, 50, 50); 
context.fill();
}
setInterval(function(){nextxy(setX,setY,50,50)}, 30);
```

Here's what i've done without calling a parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/901Lt42m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is put the parameters into an `array` like so `nextxy([setX, setY, 50, 50])` and get them by index(`circle[0]`, `circle[1]`, `circle[2]`, `circle[3]`) in your function.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/901Lt42m/4/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var circleX = 200;
var circleY = 200;
var radius = 150;
var length = 0;
var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var speed = 0.1;

function nextxy(circle) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.strokeRect(5, 5, 490, 490);
    //what's wrong with my code below?
    circle[0] = circleX + Math.cos(length) * radius;
    circle[1] = circleY + Math.sin(length) * radius;
    length += speed;
    context.beginPath();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://i60.tinypic.com/2v81rwg.png";;
    context.drawImage(img, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2], circle[3]);
    context.fill();
}
setInterval(function () {
    nextxy([setX, setY, 50, 50]);
}, 30);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @chipChocolate. Now i have another question, how to create another animation like a horizontal move in one function nextxy. Is it possible to create like this : function nextxy(circle,horizontal) { and below i create horizontal[0] = (...)

Comment: @user2207 - Are you going to pass more than one parameter to `horizontal`, when you call it through `nextxy(...)`?

Comment: Yes something like that. I want to create a different animation in one function with a different parameter to call each animation moves.

Comment: @user2207 - Yes, if you are going to pass multiple parameters then you can do the same as I've shown in my answer. ----> `horizontal[0]`, `horizontal[1]`, `horizontal[2]`,...

Comment: Wait haha, one more question. I want to try my animation in different ways. I want to draw them one by one like a queue. That i need is use "case" and "loop" right? example : (case 0)circle animation track drawn 1st , then (case 1)horizontal moves, (case 2)last the vertical moves. http://jsfiddle.net/t9tvnvot/1/

Comment: @user2207 - So, you don't want infinite loop? Ohh actually you do, but they all should animate one by one, right?

Comment: Yes that's what i want to learn and try. So i need to use "case" and "for"?

Comment: I've put case inside of the program, and i think i did something wrong with "case".

Answer (score 0):

You should to declare all arguments you need, and use it.

for example:

```
function nextxy(x, y, rx, ry) {
  ...
  setX = x + Math.cos(length) * rx;
  setY = y + Math.cos(length) * ry;
  length += speed;
  ...
}
....
nextxy(setX, setY, 50, 50);
```